# How to forward secondary domain name by nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

My webapp has two domain:`a.com` and `b.com`.But I just configed one SSL for `b.com`.

So I want nginx can forward all URL which from `*.a.com a.com` to `*.b.com b.com`

like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.a.com a.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # if use java regex： $host.replaceFirst('(.*?)a.com', '$1b.com')
}
```

Comment: Please provide details of the problem you're having. What have you tried? What error messages have you seen? What is the difference between the behaviour you're seeing and the behaviour you want?

Comment: @CalumHalpin Hello,I didn't try to do anything,I want know how to forward all requests that from `*.a.com` to `*.b.com`

Comment: Use a regular expression `server_name`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names).

Comment: Thanks,I had found answer,that is regx